# Appium hideKeyboard using javascript

Tags: angular, typescript, appium, nativescript

I've written my end to end tests using typescript + mocha + chai for Appium. I'm trying to scroll down or hide the keyboard so I can access a field during a test.

Here is my test

```
import { AppiumDriver, createDriver, SearchOptions, nsCapabilities } from "nativescript-dev-appium";
import { assert } from "chai";


describe("Create", () => {
    let driver: AppiumDriver;

    it.only("creates new item", async function () {
        driver = await createDriver();
        driver.hideKeyboard();
        const commentField = await driver.findElementByAutomationText("comment");
        await commentField.sendKeys("Used as a camera");
     }
}
```

When I run it I get the following error;

```
> node ./node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/check-dev-deps.js &&  tsc -p e2e  &&  mocha --opts ./e2e/config/mocha.opts  "--runType" "device.samsung"

e2e/1_asset_create.e2e-spec.ts:61:20 - error TS2339: Property 'hideKeyboard' does not exist on type 'AppiumDriver'.

61             driver.hideKeyboard();
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ e2e: `node ./node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/check-dev-deps.js &&  tsc -p e2e  &&  mocha --opts ./e2e/config/mocha.opts  "--runType" "device.samsung"`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/map7/.npm/_logs/2019-11-14T01_51_33_806Z-debug.log
```

Comment: @map7..as mentioned in Docs try 
- await driver.hideDeviceKeyboard();

Comment: @MukulSharma that seems to work, but I still cannot access the field, I'll start a more focused question on this problem instead